# Issue with Sound Recording in windowsphone8

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation, recording

My code works properly till page active. But after going back to another page when i again navigate on recording page it doesn't work.

here is sample code with page added.

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;
    private byte[] buffer;                             
    private MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    private SoundEffectInstance soundInstance;
    private bool soundIsPlaying = false;      

    // Status images
    private BitmapImage blankImage;
    private BitmapImage microphoneImage;
    private BitmapImage speakerImage;


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Timer to simulate the XNA Framework game loop (Microphone is 
        // from the XNA Framework). We also use this timer to monitor the 
        // state of audio playback so we can update the UI appropriately.
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Start();


        microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);

        blankImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/blank.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        microphoneImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/microphone.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        speakerImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/speaker.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }


    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
        catch { }

        if (true == soundIsPlaying)
        {
            if (soundInstance.State != SoundState.Playing)
            {
                // Audio has finished playing
                soundIsPlaying = false;

                // Update the UI to reflect that the 
                // sound has stopped playing
                SetButtonStates(true, true, false);
                UserHelp.Text = "press play\nor record";
                StatusImage.Source = blankImage;
            }
        }
    }


    private void recordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];

        stream.SetLength(0);

        microphone.Start();

        SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
        UserHelp.Text = "record";
        StatusImage.Source = microphoneImage;
    }


    private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (microphone.State == MicrophoneState.Started)
        {
            // In RECORD mode, user clicked the 
            // stop button to end recording
            microphone.Stop();
        }
        else if (soundInstance.State == SoundState.Playing)
        {
            // In PLAY mode, user clicked the 
            // stop button to end playing back
            soundInstance.Stop();
        }

        SetButtonStates(true, true, false);
        UserHelp.Text = "ready";
        StatusImage.Source = blankImage;
    }


    private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            // Update the UI to reflect that
            // sound is playing
            SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
            UserHelp.Text = "play";
            StatusImage.Source = speakerImage;

            // Play the audio in a new thread so the UI can update.
            Thread soundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(playSound));
            soundThread.Start();
        }
    }


    private void playSound()
    {
        // Play audio using SoundEffectInstance so we can monitor it's State 
        // and update the UI in the dt_Tick handler when it is done playing.
        SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
        soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
        soundIsPlaying = true;
        soundInstance.Play();
    }


    private void SetButtonStates(bool recordEnabled, bool playEnabled, bool stopEnabled)
    {
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = recordEnabled;
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = playEnabled;
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[2] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = stopEnabled;
    }
}
```

Another page

```
 public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    }
}
```

Please if possible give some solution to it because my application is dependent on audio
 recording..

Thank You very much....

Comment: DispatcherTimer don't gets disposed automatically when we navigate to another page in the app. You need to dispose the DispatcherTimer  object in OnNavigatedFrom event. May be it could relieve you to some level.

Comment: Hello, what action do you perform in your microphone_BufferReady method?

Answer (score 0):

`microphone.BufferReady -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);`

write this code into OnNavigateFrom even.